# smarty cs-cart assign a link to a variable

Tags: smarty, cs-cart

I am learning smarty. I want to assign a link to a variable:

```
{assign var="book_link" value="`$smarty.capture.$name` nofilter"}
```

I want to use truncate to produce that `book_link`, so i use

```
<div class="title-book">{$book_link|truncate:50}</div>
```

But it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the double quotes from value and try this

```
{assign var="book_link" value=`$smarty.capture.$name` nofilter}
```